# How do I add Yahoo contacts to Google Chat?

Tags: gmail, google-talk, chat, yahoo

I have several people who don't have Gmail accounts and I'd like to be able to chat with them via Google Chat in my Gmail inbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's not possible to do it using the native Gmail client. You could achieve this using a third party client like [Adium](http://adium.im/) (on Mac) or [Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/) (on Mac or Windows).

There is also [this tutorial](http://www.bigblueball.com/forums/general-other-im-news/33739-connect-google-talk-aim-msn-yahoo.html) that explains how to import your contacts via [PSI](http://psi-im.org/) messenger, but I find it rather cumbersome.

Comment: Is it possible with iChat?

Comment: I don't know, I never used iChat.